# Policy for dead letter exchange routing back to queue

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I've successfully set up a dead letter exchange policy where the `dead-letter-exchange` is blank, which will return the message to the original queue. However this only happens if the message was published to the default exchange, or with a routing key of the queue name.

If I set up a fanout or topic exchange, my message is dropped(rightfully so). Is there any way, in the RabbitMQ policy, that I can specify a routing key policy that will always point back to the queue the message was consumed off of?

Comment: I'm playing with the same thing.  Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No, and I haven't played with AMQP since the beginning of this yeah, so I haven't been actively looking for a solution either, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently messages cannot be routed back to a previous queue they were in via dead lettering.  To reiterate, if a message existed (at some point in the past) in a queue which it would be routed to by the dead letter exchange, it will not be delivered to that queue again.  Cycles are not possible with dead lettering rules, but that might be a good thing.

There was some discussion back in April 2013, which can be found here: http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2013-April/026489.html